# What is an example giving the difference between Domain Model and Data Model?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, domain-model, data-modeling, asp.net-core

I've seen many articles describing differences between Domain Model and Data Model. However none of the articles have picture representations showing difference.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507671/whats-the-difference-between-data-modelling-and-domain-modelling

Can someone provide a picture example showing difference, maybe a simple example with customers or orders, anything?
I saw one example below from resource here, however the example difference seems very little (box in red) : https://study.com/academy/lesson/domain-model-vs-data-model.html

Can someone provide an example showing a larger difference between Domain and Data? This way readers can understand

[image]

Note: Seen article [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)? 
, yet have not read concise example on the internet showing Large differences between domain and data model, anything would help.

Comment: see [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Comment: There's isn't a visual difference that defines the distinction. The difference is defined purely by their intention, i.e. what they represent. It's perfectly possible for your domain and data model to be near identical. The question as you have now posted it is hardly answerable. I suggest you rephrase to ask about the difference without explicitly asking for a visual explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen many articles describing differences between Domain Model and Data Model. However none of the articles have picture representations showing difference.

Brian Lawler's article [Domain First vs Schema First Architecture](https://medium.com/thats-what-i-m-talking-about/domain-first-vs-schema-first-architecting-6b9e381a1ccc) might help.

Or Scott Wambler [Why Data Models Shouldn't Drive Object Models](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/drivingForces.html)

Your best bet might be to look for domain models that use event sourcing.  The distinction between the domain model and the data model may be more clear when the domain model looks like business entities and the data model looks like sequences of messages.

But my searches in that vein weren't able to turn up *images* that I thought would be helpful.

[image]

[image]